# Converting complex GROUP BY and INNER JOIN SQL statement to Django ORM Level

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I am trying to convert my below mention SQL query to Django ORM layer query but I was not able to get the perfect output as provided by the SQL statement.
**Models**

```
class YearlyTable(models.Model):

   class Meta:
       db_table = 'yearlytable'
       managed = True

   user_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
   rotations = models.IntegerField()
   calories = models.FloatField()
   distance = models.FloatField()
   duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   year = models.IntegerField()
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

---

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        managed = True

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

---

```
SELECT 
users.state,
sum(yearlytable.rotations) as sum_rotations,
sum(yearlytable.calories) as sum_calories,
sum(yearlytable.distance) as sum_distance
    FROM yearlytable
    INNER JOIN users on (yearlytable.user_id = users.id)
    WHERE yearlytable.user_id in(SELECT id FROM users WHERE country LIKE 'United States%' and  NOT ("email" LIKE '%yopmail.com%'))
    GROUP BY users.state
```

Then I tried to execute the above-mentioned query using RAW Django Query Example:

```
User.objects.raw('select users.state,sum(yearlytable.rotations) as sum_rotations,sum(yearlytable.calories) as sum_calories,sum(yearlytable.distance) as sum_distance from yearlytable inner join users on (yearlytable.user_id = users.id) where yearlytable.user_id in(select id from users where country like \'United States%\' and  NOT ("email" LIKE \'%yopmail.com%\')) group by users.state;')
```

But this also didn't work. Now I don't want to use CURSOR for this as I am afraid of SQL Injection issue. So Cursor is off the table.

```
for u in User.objects.raw('select users.state,sum(yearlytable.rotations) as sum_rotations,sum(yearlytable.calories) as sum_calories,sum(yearlytable.distance) as sum_distance from yearlytable inner join users on (yearlytable.user_id = users.id) where yearlytable.user_id in(select id from users where country like \'United States%\' and  NOT ("email" LIKE \'%yopmail.com%\')) group by users.state;'):
            print u
```

**Below is the stack trace:**

```
    Traceback:
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  407.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  404.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
  51.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/widget/views.py" in heat_map
  18.         for u in User.objects.raw('select users.state,sum(yearlytable.rotations) as sum_rotations,sum(yearlytable.calories) as sum_calories,sum(yearlytable.distance) as sum_distance from yearlytable inner join users on (yearlytable.user_id = users.id) where yearlytable.user_id in(select id from users where country like \'United States%\' and  NOT ("email" LIKE \'%yopmail.com%\')) group by users.state;'):
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  1535.         query = iter(self.query)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in __iter__
  76.         self._execute_query()
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _execute_query
  90.         self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

The Django ORM which I tried was:

```
YearlyTable.objects.annotate(r=Sum('rotations'))
```

It would be great to convert this sql query to django orm level.

Comment: "But this also didn't work" how so?

Comment: i am getting "Index Error" , "tuple index out of range" message

Comment: post the full message and post your models

Comment: thanks for updating the question but that's not a stacktrace

Comment: http://dpaste.com/0M4GVAY --> actual stacktrace @e4c5

Comment: Unusual for the for u in rawquery to produce that stack trace. My guess is that it's because you are not selecting the primary key in the users table that's needed when you do a raw query with model managers but generally that produces a different error

Answer (score 3):

### **Assumptions**:

1. Use django ORM without resorting to raw SQL
2. Design the django models idiomatically, meaning related tables should use models ForeignKey, OneonOne or ManytoMany attributes.
3. YearlyTable assumed to have a one to one relationship with user.

### **In models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email


class YearlyTable(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField('User', unique=True)
    rotations = models.IntegerField()
    calories = models.FloatField()
    distance = models.FloatField()
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

I populated the tables with the following sample data:

```
    u = User(email='a@w.com', first_name='ab', city='New York', state='New York', postal_code='12345', country='United States')
    y = YearlyTable(user=u, rotations=10, calories=10.8, distance=12.5, duration=20, year=2011)

    u = User(email='b@w.com', first_name='ac', city='Buffalo', state='New York', postal_code='67891', country='United States') 
    y = YearlyTable(user=u, rotations=8, calories=11.8, distance=11.5, duration=30, year=2012)

    u = User(email='c@w.com', first_name='ad', city='Rochester', state='New York', postal_code='13579', country='United States')
    y = YearlyTable(user=u, rotations=20, calories=15.8, distance=13.5, duration=40, year=2013)

    u = User(email='d@w.com', first_name='ae', city='Pittsburgh', state='Pennsylvania', postal_code='98765', country='United States')
    y = YearlyTable(user=u, rotations=30, calories=10.2, distance=12.5, duration=40, year=2012)

    u = User(email='e@w.com', first_name='af', city='Los Angeles', state='California', postal_code='97531', country='United States')
    y = YearlyTable(user=u, rotations=10, calories=14.8, distance=13.5, duration=10, year=2010)
```

### Checking the physical tables and querying directly against it

```
    psql -d 

    # select * from testapp_user;
     id | password | last_login |  email  | first_name |    city     |    state     | postal_code |    country
    ----+----------+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------------
      1 |          |            | a@w.com | ab         | New York    | New York     |       12345 | United States
      2 |          |            | b@w.com | ac         | Buffalo     | New York     |       67891 | United States
      3 |          |            | c@w.com | ad         | Rochester   | New York     |       13579 | United States
      4 |          |            | d@w.com | ae         | Pittsburgh  | Pennsylvania |       98765 | United States
      5 |          |            | e@w.com | af         | Los Angeles | California   |       97531 | United States
    (5 rows)

    # select * from testapp_yearlytable;
     id | rotations | calories | distance | duration | year |            created            |           modified            | user_id
    ----+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------
      1 |        10 |     10.8 |     12.5 |       20 | 2011 | 2016-05-17 16:23:46.39941+00  | 2016-05-17 16:23:46.399445+00 |       1
      3 |         8 |     11.8 |     11.5 |       30 | 2012 | 2016-05-17 16:24:26.264569+00 | 2016-05-17 16:24:26.264606+00 |       2
      4 |        20 |     15.8 |     13.5 |       40 | 2013 | 2016-05-17 16:24:51.200739+00 | 2016-05-17 16:24:51.200785+00 |       3
      5 |        30 |     10.2 |     12.5 |       40 | 2012 | 2016-05-17 16:25:08.187799+00 | 2016-05-17 16:25:08.187852+00 |       4
      6 |        10 |     14.8 |     13.5 |       10 | 2010 | 2016-05-17 16:25:24.846284+00 | 2016-05-17 16:25:24.846324+00 |       5
    (5 rows)


    # SELECT
    testapp_user.state,
    sum(testapp_yearlytable.rotations) as sum_rotations,
    sum(testapp_yearlytable.calories) as sum_calories,
    sum(testapp_yearlytable.distance) as sum_distance
    FROM testapp_yearlytable
    INNER JOIN  testapp_user on (testapp_yearlytable.user_id = testapp_user.id)
    WHERE testapp_yearlytable.user_id in
    (SELECT id FROM testapp_user
    WHERE country LIKE 'United States%' and
    NOT ("email" LIKE '%a@w.com%'))
    GROUP BY testapp_user.state;

        state     | sum_rotations | sum_calories | sum_distance
    --------------+---------------+--------------+--------------
     New York     |            28 |         27.6 |           25
     Pennsylvania |            30 |         10.2 |         12.5
     California   |            10 |         14.8 |         13.5
```

### Running in python shell

```
    > python manage.py shell
    Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18)
    [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    (InteractiveConsole)
    >>> from testapp.models import User, YearlyTable
    >>> from django.db.models import Q, Sum
    >>> User.objects.filter(~Q(email__icontains='a@w.com'), country__startswith='United States') \
    ... .values('state') \
    ... .annotate(sum_rotations = Sum('yearlytable__rotations'), \
    ... sum_calories = Sum('yearlytable__calories'), \
    ... sum_distance = Sum('yearlytable__distance'))
    [{'sum_rotations': 28, 'state': u'New York', 'sum_calories': 27.6, 'sum_distance': 25.0}, {'sum_rotations': 30, 'state': u'Pennsylvania', 'sum_calories': 10.2, 'sum_distance': 12.5}, {'sum_rotations': 10, 'state': u'California', 'sum_calories': 14.8, 'sum_distance': 13.5}]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, But as you can see in models.py file my column name "user_id" is not a foreign key. It is an integer field. Now for some reasons I can't change my model file and make necessary changes in DB.

Comment: I did try your answer but I am getting the same error like below :

File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1389, in raise_field_error
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'yearlytable' into field. Choices are: apnsdevice, auth_token, city, company, country, created, date_of_birth, email, facebo

Comment: That error is due to your code subverting the django model relationship design, which I stated in my assumption not to do, as it will lead to future technical debt in using too many hacks down the road. You would be better off fixing this design issue now to assure good maintainability.

Comment: If you still want to go ahead with it, you cannot accomplish the group by output using raw, since the primary key requirement for the raw SQL will render the group by output useless.  You can try using cursors. The raw SQL you showed in your question is not using params / placeholder variables which carries the same risk for SQL injection. So I do not understand your SQL injection concern specific to cursors. In order to avoid SQL injection use params. I would strongly suggest fixing the design issue which I understand may not be a small feat, but you will be much better off down the road.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this can be done using the [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/) with the following ORM query:

1) We filter on the `User` to find those which match the inner most `SELECT` statement. This is returns a list of the `User.id`.

2) values() is used first on the `YearlyTable` will perform the `GROUP BY` on `User.state`.

3) distinct() is used to ensure we only account for each possible `User.state` once.

4) [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) is used to perform the `Sum` of the values you wanted.

5) Finally we call values() again to make dictionaries containing the information you requested in the top level `SELECT` query.

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

YearlyTable.objects.filter(
    user_id__in=User.objects.filter(
        country__startswith='United States'
    ).exclude(
        email__contains='yopmail.com'
    ).values_list('id', flat=True)
).values('user__state').distinct().annotate(
    sum_rotations=Sum('rotations'),
    sum_calories=Sum('calories'),
    sum_distance=Sum('distance')
).values('user__state', 'sum_rotations', 'sum_calories', 'sum_distance')
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:  
File "/home/akki/rest_api/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1389, in raise_field_error
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: calories, created, distance, duration, id, modified, rotations, user_id, year

Comment: Similarly to BobbyC, I would advocate that you migrate the `user_id` field to a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model, since it would also simplify the statement:```YearlyTable.objects.filter(
    user__in=User.objects.filter(
        country__startswith='United States'
    ).exclude(
        email__contains='yopmail.com'
    )
).values('user__state').distinct().annotate(
    sum_rotations=Sum('rotations'),
    sum_calories=Sum('calories'),
    sum_distance=Sum('distance')
).values('user__state', 'sum_rotations', 'sum_calories', 'sum_distance')```